# Blue blur on the side of PagerAdapter

Tags: java, android

I'm using a PagerAdapter to flip through pictures, and when I get to the ends of the set and try to flip further, I get a blue fade that appears along the right side of my view. When I flip back to the beginning and try to flip one more to the left, I get a blue blur on the left side.

Any ideas? Here's my PagerAdapter code:

```
public class PictureFlipperAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
String[] images;
MediaHelper mh;
public PictureFlipperAdapter(Context context,String[] images){
    this.context=context;
    this.images=images;
    mh=MediaHelper.getInstance(context);
    for (String img : images) Log.v("Image",img);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
    imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);


    //Resize the image to just fit the window and return it
    Bitmap resizedImg=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(images[position]);

    //Log.v("image size",resizedImg.getByteCount()+"");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedImg);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
    return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}



}
```

[image: Blue blur on sides of PagerAdapter]

Comment: somewhy it seems to me like you have null background for this activity. am i right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that each view didn't necessarily fill up the entire page -- the View object was just set to wrap content, so the rest of the screen outside of the image was undefined. The solution was just to make sure the view filled the entire parent screen.

Once I did this, I didn't get the weird drawing issues.